# VBA Code won't execute because of ActiveX Elements (Error 32809)

Tags: vba, excel, activex, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have a file which has ActiveX Elements in it that are linked to VBA Code. This file worked fine up until about 1.5 months ago. Now I suspected that it stopped working because of problems with an MS Update that was described [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/12/11/recent-update-of-office-causes-problems-with-activex-controls/) and [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/office-update-breaks-activex-controls/).

So far so good.

The computer it is running on has Office 2010 installed. I dutifully checked if the update was installed. It was not.

In fact, the articles described that the ActiveX controlls stop working if the update is installed. Upon further testing, I realized that some of the conrols continued to work! So I thought that couldn't be it anymore...

...and yet... it does seem to be the problem.

I created and tested two files: **One with ActiveX Controls** and **one with Form Controls**. Same controls, same code. Really simple code. Here it is:

```
Sub Schaltfläche2_Klicken()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection = 1000
    End With
End Sub
```

Both versions ran just fine on my own computer which has Excel 2013 installed, with the MS update, AND the fix cited in the articles applied! **Yet on the 2010 Version that it needs to run on only the Form Controls one ran as it should!**

The ActiveX Version created a **VBA Error 32809**! It errored out on the `.Range` line.

I tested further... tried to reference a cell using `.cells(1,1)` which yielded the same error again! Dito for a straight forward selection of `.Range("A1")`.

Finally, I tried recording a macro. That worked, and the code it produced refrenced cells like this, which is normal:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10000"
```

I checked the macro security settings. Everything is activated. There is no special setting like "Lotus Compatibility" selected. "Z1S1" reference style isn't active either. Neither of these should influence VBA code in my opinion, but it was the only thing I could think of looking at.

Lastly, I **could no longer select the ActiveX Elements with the mouse.** While they continued to work, I could not select them or right klick them so that the menu comes up to edit them!

So there you are... Does anyone know why this would happen? Has anyone else had this? Any thing else I could look at? I've been searching the intertubes and come up short.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is the updates. You will have this problem if you try to use a workbook on multiple PCs and they don't all have the update and fix applied, or all **not** have it. It's a nightmare.

Comment: @Rory Have you found anything documented someplace? Microsoft perhaps?

Comment: There's a KB article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036/EN-US

Comment: @Rory Thanks. The issue described is the right one. The solution provided is ofcourse not at all workable or only with a huge hassle. Arrgh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here is my non solution solution to my own problem.

Microsoft tells you that the solution to the problem is to install the faulty update they published on all other computers as well and then go fix each one manually. Naturally, I don't have the admin rights to do that, nor the time to implement it.

Saddly this left me with only one solution to the problem. **Take out all ActiveX Controlls and replace them with Form Controlls.**

After doing this, my spreadsheet, all my code, and the form controlls work perfectly in ANY excel version.

I REALLY HOPE that Microsoft comes up with a better solution, because the current one will not be workable for the vast majority of people.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: maybe there's something wrong with the FM20.DLL library.
You might check with

```
Sub M_snb()
  c00 = Replace(Mid(Environ(6), 9), "\cmd.exe", "\FM20.DLL")
  MsgBox CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & c00 & """").stdout.readall
End Sub
```

Comment: Will check on this and report bach when I can.